# how to get all Bootstrap (css, js, fonts) paths using bower?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower

`bower list --paths` gives the following:

```
>bower list --paths

  bootstrap: [
    'bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less',
    'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
  ],
  jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```

the command does not give paths for `bootstrap.css` files. Which `bower` command will give all the required paths (css, js, fonts etc)of a package.

Answer (score 1):

You should install bootstrap-css version.

```
bower install bootstrap-css --save
bower list --paths


bootstrap: [
    'bower_components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css',
    'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
],
jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```